# WebAudio - What JS timer should be used?

Tags: javascript, timer, web-audio-api

**UPDATE: I've concluded that this whole thing is just an annoying bug that's been introduced in version 32 of google chrome, and all that changing the timer would do is avoiding the actual bug root instead of pushing chromium developers to fix it..**

**Check this topic out:  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356772**

### ---------------------------------

Archived topic contents

> there's a webaudio powered music site designed for Chrome that I'm
>   trying to help-out with, and I need some advice:
>
> Once the client receives the music-notes, the notes are scheduled
>   through a timer to run after the specified delay (1000ms by default)
>   to compensate for network ping issues.
>
> Originally, this was done through using the WebAudio-native timers for
>   all 1000ms.  This turned out to be VERY taxing on the CPU when up to
>   ~600 notes are being scheduled at a time. (considering it's my
>   understanding that all those notes callback every milisecond, and is
>   forced to not skip any callbacks)
>
> So a patch was recently made, where SetTimeOut would be used for the
>   first 990ms of the schedule and WebAudio for the rest.  This made a
>   HUGE performance improvement.
>
> There's a problem, that if the tab is out of focus, the browser
>   throttles the accuracy of SetTimeout/SetInterval from 4ms to 1000ms,
>   which causes glitchy/non-working audio when changing tabs.  So a
>   workaround has been added to this and been implimented to the site;
>   create a WebWorker thread and put the SetTimeout rendering in it. 
>   This works very well on multi-core systems, however this causes major
>   hanging issues with single-core systems (both system and/or browser
>   level).
>
> ---
>
> Bottom line, I think the true way to fix this is through avoiding the
>   Web-Workers workaround and using a different timer system other than
>   SetTimeout or SetInterval to avoid page-invisability throttling.  So,
>   what's a good timer to use that has the same (or less) CPU footprint
>   as Javascript, has a 8ms or better accuracy, and doesn't get throttled
>   by the browser?

Comment: I am interested to learn more about the architecture of your code that would result in the web audio timers taking up so much CPU.

Are you saying you create a 1ms timer, check if it is the right time to play the note, and if not check again in 1ms? With the web audio API you should be able to simply schedule the notes for the exact time you want them to play, so one call to `AudioBufferSourceNode.start` or `OscillatorNode.start` for each note, for example.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I looked into this some more, and it turns out this is a browser-issue introduced by a modern version of chrome (probably starting with version 32, when they apparently started using a new method of handling WebAudio performance). I've reported this in the google forums, doubting that google would notice tho: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/windows7/33-Beta/hcHp4w0TV2g

<br/>I'm not the developer of the site, but I help him fix bugs the best I can, and I'm the most knowledgeable about this bug.

Comment: If you want to check out the code check these out:  ||
SoundManager implimentation:  http://www.multiplayerpiano.com/soundmanager2/soundmanager2.js  || Audio Engine: http://www.multiplayerpiano.com/script.js  ||
Web Worker: http://www.multiplayerpiano.com/workerTimer.js  ||
To test out single-core perf for yourselves w Chrome: http://www.multiplayerpiano.com/NMPB%20private%20test  ||
To test intensive songs, try any of these commands: "_/play 7291_", "_/play 190_", "_/play 669_", or "_/play 12553_".  || 
The notequota is 1800 notes. Further ways to improve cpu efficentcy are still appreciated.

Comment: Check this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/

Comment: I've concluded that this whole thing is just an annoying bug, that's been introduced in version 32 of google chrome, and all changing the timer would do is avoiding the actual bug root instead of pushing chromium developers to fix it..